# Auto-import facebook gallerues to Wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, import

I'm searching for a plugin that auto-importo all facebook album, to galleries in wordpress. The website page is www.saggin.com.br/novo !! In www.saggin.com.br/fotos.html I'm using my client-side plugin to take photos from facebook. But now I'm using a wordpress theme, and I need that same function. I try to use IFTTT but It only creat a post, not a gallery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at a plugin called "[Facebook Walleria](http://zoxion.com/walleria/)" it is not a free plugin but it does work great and makes it easy to import your facebook albums to wordpress. you can get it from [Codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-walleria-wordpress-plugin/634775)

Hope it help

Comment: This plugin import a layout with my albums?
I need a plugin that import albums to galleries tab in wordpress, and creat a new Gallery.